# IronPython in Visual STudio

Tags: python, visual-studio, ironpython

I have installed the latest IronPython build in Windows, and also installed the Python tools in Visual Studio 2017 Community Version. However, when I tried to use the IronPython 2.7 as the Python environments, and tried to install the packages through pip. It comes into errors:

```
----- Installing 'pip' -----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
----- Failed to install 'pip' -----

----- Installing 'opencv-python==3.4.1.15' -----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
----- Failed to install 'opencv-python==3.4.1.15' -----
```

I already run VS using administrator and it should have the right to install. Any idea on why that happened and how to fix that?